# prevent video array from looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, html5-video

this seems like the opposite problem that anyone ever has. Basically, the videos (html5) in an array play, but for the life of me, I can't seem to keep them from automatically looping. I've tried just having it play the next video only if the index value is less that the array length,

```
if(currentVideo < videos.length){
                playVideo( (currentVideo + 1) % videos.length );

            }
```

but for some reason its still looping, and it shouldn't... What am i doing wrong here? Or iis there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try incrementing `currentVideo`.

```
if ( currentVideo < videos.length ) {
    playVideo( currentVideo++ );
}
```

Comment: Ah, you want it to stop after it reaches the end of the array?

Comment: Sorry, without more code, it is hard to tell what you are trying to do. Is `currentVideo` starting at 0? and how are you using it?

Comment: oh, yeah, but, I got it. if it's `currentVideo + 1`, but doesn't have `% videos.length`, it works. So, thanks